# Changing the font of algorithm name in algo.sty

Tags: fonts, algorithms

I am using [`algo.sty`](http://www.win.tue.nl/~kbuchin/teaching/algo.sty) to write algorithm in LaTeX. I want that the algorithm names are in `\texttt` font. I guess I need to change something about the `\a@paralgo` (from [`algo.sty`](http://www.win.tue.nl/~kbuchin/teaching/algo.sty)) in the below code, but I could not figure out how to do that.

For example when I write

```
\begin{algorithm}{AlgoName}{  
test algo
\end{algorithm}
```

I want to change the font of AlgoName to `\texttt`.

```
\def\algorithm#1{%
  \ifa@numbered
  \refstepcounter{\a@counter}%
  \else
  \edef\@currentlabel{\noexpand\a@noargproc{#1}}%
  \fi
  \@ifnextchar[{\a@paralgo{#1}}{\a@genalgo{\qproc{#1}}}% match ]
  }
%
\def\a@paralgo#1[#2]{\a@genalgo{\qproc[{#2}]{#1}}}
%
\def\a@genalgo#1#2{%
  \list{\arabic{a@line}.\hfill}%
  {\usecounter{a@line}
    \itemsep 0pt
    \parsep 0pt
    \leftmargin 2em
    \rightmargin 0pt
    \labelwidth 2em
    \labelsep 0pt
    \let\\=\a@cr
    }
  \ifa@numbered
  \item[\textbf{Algorithm\ \thealgorithm}]
    \ignorespaces #2
  \else
  \item[\textbf{Algorithm\ {#1}}]
    \ignorespaces #2
  \fi
  \item
    }
\def\endalgorithm{\endlist}
```

Comment: Try to change (use `\ttfamily`) `\textbf{Algorithm\ \thealgorithm}` but make sure that you have a font which supports bold face in mono spaced family. For example, load `lmodern`.

Comment: It changes the font of text "Algorithm", but I want to change the algorithm name that I give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change `\textbf` to `\texttt` twice in the definition of `\a@genalgo` (lines marked `% here` in the example below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algo}

\makeatletter
\def\a@genalgo#1#2{%
  \list{\arabic{a@line}.\hfill}%
  {\usecounter{a@line}
    \itemsep 0pt
    \parsep 0pt
    \leftmargin 2em
    \rightmargin 0pt
    \labelwidth 2em
    \labelsep 0pt
    \let\\=\a@cr
    }
  \ifa@numbered
  \item[\texttt{Algorithm\ \thealgorithm}]% here
    \ignorespaces #2
  \else
  \item[\texttt{Algorithm\ {#1}}]% here
    \ignorespaces #2
  \fi
  \item
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{algorithm}{}{}
test algorithm
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

### Update

After an edit to the question, the change has to be applied to the name supplied, so you need to change `\a@noargproc` and `\a@proc` from their original definition

```
\def\a@noargproc#1{{\it #1\/}}
\def\a@proc[#1]#2{{\it #2\/}{\rm ($#1$)}}
```

to

```
\def\a@noargproc#1{{\ttfamily #1}}
\def\a@proc[#1]#2{{\ttfamily #2}{\rmfamily ($#1$)}}
```

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algo}

\makeatletter
\def\a@noargproc#1{{\ttfamily #1\/}}
\def\a@proc[#1]#2{{\ttfamily #2}{\rmfamily ($#1$)}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}{testAlgo}{}
test algorithm
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

By the way, it's better not to change `algo.sty` directly; either make the changes in your document, as I did in my example, or save a copy of `algo.sty` with a different name and make the change there (of course, load this saved copy in your `.tex` instead of the original `algo` package).

Comment: I edit my question since I think there is a misunderstanding. I want to change the font of algorithm name that I give.

Comment: @user1914367 this is even easier. See my updated answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, after reading the `sty` it was possible to find that command. But it was hard to follow those dozen of commands. lol

Comment: @user1914367 please see my updated answer. You also need to redefine another command, in case the optional argument is used.